# While Function and cin in C++

Tags: c++

Its been a few days since I started reading Stroustrup's book Programming principles and practices. His grammar repetition detection code is the following,

```
string previous = " ";
string current;
while (cin >> current){
    if (previous == current)
        cout << "repeated word:" << current << "\n";
    previous = current;
}
```

Although he explained the while statement, I didn't quite understand how a whole sentence can be analyzed using the combination of while and cin. If it takes the sentence word by word, then what is it that exactly dictates that. For example, why doesn't it stop with the first word only.

Comment: You might want to check this link http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson3.html

It explains FOR, WHILE and DO WHILE loops, how they actually work. It is not hard to understand, you just need to know when do the loops actually ask themself how far they are, and then choose what u  need or adapt one loop to work with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering, because from your comments, your problem seems to
be different from the issues the other answers address.

`std::istream` is a stream; the form of sequential input used in
C++.  (It can also be used for certain forms of non-sequential
input, but that's an advanced feature, tricky to use, and it
doesn't need to concern us here.)  The important aspect of
sequential input, or a stream, is that it *extracts* data from
its source, and once the data is extracted, it is no longer
there to be accessed.  Logically, it can be thought of as
a position marker into the data in the file; each time it
extracts a character, the position marker advances, and it
always extracts at the position marker.  So when you write:

```
std::string dest;
std::cin >> dest;
```

the `>>` operator (which is nothing other than a function with
a special name, as you'll see later in the book) first extracts
characters until it finds one that isn't white space; then
extracts characters until it finds one that is white space,
putting each character it extracts into `dest`.  It will also
stop if there are no more characters to be extracted,
a condition called end of file.  If that happens before it has
put any characters into `dest`, the input will fail; this
failure will be memorized in the stream, and will be used when
you use the stream in a context which requires a true or false:
the stream is true unless it has failed.

But the important point to retain is that the stream never
extracts the same character twice.  If you want to see this
better, the stream has some low level functions which allow you
to extract the data, character by character.  You might want to
try:

```
char ch;
while ( std::cin.get( ch ) ) {
    std::cout << ch << std::endl;
}
```

`std::istream::get` is a very, very low level input, which
always extracts exactly one character, without skipping white
space, or anything.  All the `>>` does is call this function
until it has finished its task.  It's a little bit more
complicated; in particular, `>>` often cannot know whether it
has finished until it has looked one character too far, so there
are means to peek at the next character, without extracting it,
and a means of pushing last character you've extracted back into
the front of the stream, so you can read it again.  And there
are means of managing error status.  (Say you do `>>` into an
`int`, but the next characters to be read are "abc".)  But for
the moment, you don't have to worry about all that.  For the
moment, just remember that once a character has been read, it's
gone, and can never be read again.

Comment: `"...once a character has been read, it's gone, and can never be read again.`" - This is true only for the standard input stream object `std::cin`, correct? Because this is possible for file and string streams. BTW +1.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's a simplification; you have to do additional work to go back and read previously read characters, and it doesn't always work.  (It has nothing to do with whether you're reading `std::cin` or another `std::istream`.  It depends on the underlying device: if it's a pipe or a keyboard, you can't effectively seek (and the seek operations will fail); if it's a file, you can, to a limited degree.  (If the file is opened in text mode, the default, to a very limited degree.)  But this is all advanced programming.  For beginners, once a character has been read, it's gone.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and clear explanation; it was just want I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple.

```
while (cin >> current)
```

reads the input until there's nothing left inside. The standard overloaded `operator>>` skips over whitespace and then reads everything until it encounters another whitespace character or reaches the end of the input. Since it's inside a `while` loop, it'll be called in every iteration of the loop. That's why the sentence is split in words.

Comment: So basically, it takes the first word in and then it stops at the space. When it stops, it loops back to the beginning and it continues to the next word. Right? But, why doesn't it restart to the beginning.

Comment: @user29568 Because it is input.  It's already read the first word.

Comment: @JamesKanze Well, surely if it was dumb then it would come back to the beginning. And stay stuck in a meaningless loop. So, cin takes the first word and compares it to " " getting false. What makes it jump to the next word?

Comment: @user29568 Reading removes the data from the stream.  It's possible to go back and get it again, but this requires added intelligence in the stream.  I've posted an answer trying to describe what I think you're missing, but the basic response is simple: reading a character from a stream removes it from the stream.  It's gone, forever.  (Which isn't quite true, but for  keyboard input, it's very, very near to being true.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to think as algorithm:

```
While the text isn t complete
    read a word
    if this word is like the previous one
        there s a repeated word
    store this word for next iteration
```

`while (cin >> current)` will send one word after another until cin is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, it'll read words until there are none left! Once the end of the input is reached, or a non-string is encountered (well, good luck with that), an *error flag* is set on the stream. `cin >> current` evaluates to `cin`, which in turn can convert to boolean `false` when an error flag is set. Since you're using `cin >> current` as a loop condition, this ends the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` is an instance of `istream` template class. `operator >>` acts on this istream instance  to load input into data and returns a reference to this `istream`. Then it is tested by a call of `cin::operator void*()` which invokes `fail()` function to test if operation succeeded. This is why you can use this operation in while condition

```
while ( cin >> current)
{
   //...
```