# How can Cin be used in an if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, cin

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this:

Can anyone tell me what this does? (Ps: this is my 3rd day of coding and I really want to understand this example)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpchI.png]

```
if (std::cin >> currVal){
while (std::cin >> val){
```

Comment: I'm following a beginner's textbook and this was in one of their examples. I tried reading their explanation but I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: I have added an image of the example in the textook. From what I have learnt cin >> is a way of getting the user to input something. I don't understand how this can be used in a if statement or while loop. Because for if and while loops they need a comparison like =! or >= or ==.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I've read that and still don't quite understand.

Comment: See also [While Function and cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633606/while-function-and-cin-in-c) and [C++ : cin inside a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038373/c-cin-inside-a-while-loop) and [c++ when will while(cin>>s) stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999994/c-when-will-whilecins-stop)

Comment: I've added a more detailed answer to the duplicate, I hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791520/if-cin-x-why-can-you-use-that-condition/60109776#60109776

Answer (score 0):

It pretty much sais: pipe in the value of `number` into Cin. Which is C's inputstream. This `if`-condition will fail if `number` is not a number and will evaluate to false.

Your syntax is incorrect. What you meant to do was `if ( cin >> number)`.

In the comments, a question regarding strings arose:

> Every input is a string. If you want to check if the string you entered is a number you can simply to convert it to one. You have to cin a string, and then convert it using eg. strol
>
> An alternative could be to check if the reading from cin failed, but i generally don't use this approach because `cin.fail()` covers more error situations than just a failed type conversion.

You can read more here about [cin here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

Comment: What if `number` is a string? The answer is not complete. You didn't answer why you can use it. You only answered what will happen.

Comment: @ThomasSablik There you go sir.

Comment: Now it's even worse. How can the input stream return something that's not a string? You should at least mention the return type of `operator>>`, the failbits and how a stream is casted to bool.

Comment: @walnut it kinda does - `This if-condition will fail if number is not a number and will evaluate to false.`

Comment: @walnut that wasn't his question. And, I can read between the lines...

Comment: @user1234213211 OP has clarified the question now. So my stated issue is resolved. But before, it wasn't clear whether OP's textbook wasn't just wrong.

Comment: The question is why you can use the operator<< in the if condition. What is the returned value and how is it casted to bool

Comment: @ThomasSablik That is answered....

Comment: I don't see it in your answer. What exactly is returned?